# JHipster Application doesn't be deployed to Heroku

Tags: heroku, jhipster, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to deploy my jhipster application to Heroku with yo jhipster:heroku command.But application doesn't start.
'heroku logs --tail' commands shows:

> 2017-06-22T13:06:43.498695+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-06-22 13:06:43.498 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.487869+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-06-22 13:06:43.482  WARN 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1458ed9c: startup date [Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@10e41621)
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.498697+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.498699+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Could not copy property 'password' from source to target; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> 2017-06-22T13:06:43.498713+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.498714+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.498715+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.498714+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.498716+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.498716+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(BeanUtils.java:617)
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.498717+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 16 common frames omitted
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.498718+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid URL: ${JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_URL}/config
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.498719+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigClientProperties.extractCredentials(ConfigClientProperties.java:258)
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.498719+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigClientProperties.getPassword(ConfigClientProperties.java:170)
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.498720+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 21 common frames omitted
>   2017-06-22T13:06:43.498721+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2017-06-22T13:06:48.579401+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Xmx256m -jar target/*.war --spring.profiles.active=prod,heroku --server.port=46450`
>   2017-06-22T13:06:49.784412+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
>   2017-06-22T13:06:49.787364+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>   2017-06-22T13:06:55.512505+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2017-06-22T13:06:55.502911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>   2017-06-22T13:06:55.402089+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-06-22 13:06:55.397  WARN 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@10a9d961: startup date [Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@10e41621)
>   2017-06-22T13:06:55.412301+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2017-06-22T13:06:55.362819+00:00 app[web.1]: :: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE ::
>   2017-06-22T13:06:55.412303+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(BeanUtils.java:625)
>   2017-06-22T13:06:55.412298+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-06-22 13:06:55.411 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>   2017-06-22T13:06:55.412303+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(BeanUtils.java:537)
>   2017-06-22T13:06:55.412304+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigClientProperties.override(ConfigClientProperties.java:317)
>   2017-06-22T13:06:55.412306+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:93)
>   2017-06-22T13:06:55.412302+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Could not copy property 'password' from source to target; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   2017-06-22T13:06:55.412307+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:611)

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out what was wrong with this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739617/error-when-starting-jhipster-application-on-heroku

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when starting jHipster application on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739617/error-when-starting-jhipster-application-on-heroku)