# Error when starting jHipster application on heroku

Tags: heroku, jhipster, jhipster-registry

i'm using jhipster 4.5.6. I'm trying to run my application on heroku and i'm getting this error when executing this code on in main class:

Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();

2017-06-24 17:35:32.293 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
2017-06-24T17:35:32.294416+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-06-24T17:35:32.294418+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Could not copy property 'password' from source to target; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Here is the completed log:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid URL: ${JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_URL}/config

Comment: So it seems you did not configure an environment variable for the jhipster registry. Are you using microservices architecture? If not there's no obvious reason for your app to use service discovery feature offered by the registry.

Comment: I'm not using microservices architecture, the application deployed on heroku is thee basic template generated by jhipster, how can i disable the service discovery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You generated a monolith app with service discovery enabled, this is why your app expects JHipster registry URL to be configured. You should edit your `.yo-rc.json` file and set `"serviceDiscoveryType": false` and re-generate your app with `yo jhipster --with-entities`.